# How to show data from many models and sort it in one table (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, join

I have four models call it A B C D and all I want to do is display and sort it in one table like this

```
+----+-------+---------------------+-------+
| 1. | B-5   | 2018-12-11 10:52:22 | 20    |
+----+-------+---------------------+-------+
| 2. | A-4   | 2018-12-11 09:52:22 | 10    |
+----+-------+---------------------+-------+
| 3. | C-3   | 2018-12-11 08:52:22 | 20    |
+----+-------+---------------------+-------+
```

for the SQL Query it looks like this

```
SELECT `code`, `updated_at`, `qty` FROM `a`
UNION ALL
SELECT `code`, `updated_at`, `qty` FROM `b`
UNION ALL
SELECT `code`, `updated_at`, `qty` FROM `c`
UNION ALL
SELECT `code`, `updated_at`, `qty` FROM `d`
ORDER BY `updated_at`
```

is it possible to do that? and if it possible how to do it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins

Comment: You can use `DB::raw()` for writing pure sql statement in eloquent query builder methods, 
But also you can create a `View` in your database and easily query that view

Answer (score 0):

Use Joins for this, Here is an example:

```
$codes= DB::table('a')
            ->join('b', 'a.id', '=', 'b.user_id')
            ->join('c', 'a.id', '=', 'c.user_id')
            ->join('d', 'a.id', '=', 'd.user_id')
            ->select('a.*', 'b.*', 'c.*')
            ->orderBy('a.updated_at','desc')
            ->get();
```